# Generating excel file from .net code without having excel client installed

Tags: .net, excel

I'm in need of programmatically generating from .net code an excel file (xlsx) doing classic things such as add the the excel autofilter, set cell/range data types, format presentation of data in columns and rows, define conditional formatting rules, add formulas, etc.

What are the existing options?

Comment: If only you just wanted to put data into an already-fancy sheet, you could use one of the xmldocument libraries to do it. All those features you discuss are very difficult to pull off properly without excel.

Comment: My need is to create excel files from scratch. I was looking for some quick high level libraries to achieve the result. Would you suggest starting from xmldocument level libraries or look for some other higher level library that abstracts away the underlying file system?

Comment: Higher level? Why excel as the output?

Comment: Is it not clear what it means higher level? Excel as the output because It's a requirement.

Comment: Really it is not clear what higher level means? I'd say it's something that abstracts out many details. If you compare Open XML SDK (low level framework) and EPPlus (higher level framework) you should get what I meant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open XML SDK is one possibility (https://github.com/officedev/open-xml-sdk) that is probably more challenging at it operates at a low file system level and EPPlus
(https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus) is another higher level popular alternative.